# multiple attribute values for shortcodes in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

How to create a shortcode with multiple attribute values? f.e

```
[contact type="phone"]74847848[/contact]
 and 
[contact type="fax"]5565656565[/contact]


  function sc_kontakti($atts, $content = null) {




return '<div class="sckon '.$type.'">'.$content.'</div>';
 }
 add_shortcode("kontakti", "sc_kontakti");
```

Answer (score 2):

$atts should be an array with all the attributes entered in your shortcode. for example

```
[contact type="phone" number="8888888"]
```

should give you

```
$atts['type']="phone"
$atts['number']="8888888"
```

And then you can work with those values to return the code outputted by the shortcode.

Comment: Ok, probably I mistyped. I wanted to say multiple attribute values.

Comment: So you would like something like an array of values with a value? like $atts['type']['0'] would equal something?

Comment: yes - phone, fax, email,address.  Better that kind [contact type="phone"]74847848[/contact]

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

im using the Shortcoder plugin to that. Could solve your problem. He automaticly creates values that you can type in, and add a button to the editor. here goes the link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcoder/